# Render two separate components in React App

Tags: reactjs

I am not experienced enough React delevoper yet, so i am having issue with rendering 2 separate components, which are comunicate with each other. So the main task is simple:

- user click the button `create user form`
- adding 1 component combination

Btw i want to provide to user the possibility to create as much component combination as he will want. What pattern should i look for? I don't understand how to create two communicating components inside different parent containers.

Here is gif for better understanding

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Main is a component and Sidebar is a component you want to store state in Main and pass props to Sidebar.

Make Main a stateful class based component with a constructor function and store something like this:

```
this.state = {
    addInput: false  
}
```

Then in Main write a click handler. When the user clicks a button set addInput to true.

```
function addComponent() => {
    this.setState({
       addInput: !this.state.addInput
    })
}
```

Add an onClick event handler to the button like this:

```
<input type="button" onClick={this.addComponent()} />
```

Then inside Main pass props to Sidebar:

```
<SideBar addInput={this.state.addInput} />
```

Then inside Sidebar you can use `props` and a ternary to decide whether or not to display the input section based on whether addInput is true or false.

I wrote this quick and it's a basic rundown. Check out the [React props docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for more information.

Instead of using a boolean inside Main's state you could also use a number and dictate how many input boxes show up in Sidebar based on the number value.

[Here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-edison-n42o0) that I wrote showing another person how to pass props in a React component. Check it out and you'll see an example of passing props to a child component. Look at Parent and Child components and see how props are passed and also state being updated by an onClick event.